# Android emitting RF at X frequency

Tags: radio-firmware

First, nothing illegal heare. My (ours) gate remote controll have broken (all 5). The provider have gone - death, bankrupt, I don't know. The remote have no logo or some ID, but the instructions are kind to tell me that transmission frequency are 868.35 MHz +- 200 KHz. My question is if I can controll an android to emit on this freq.(I know, it may be a code emited to, but first things first...)

Comment: The RF hardware in those devices is not a general radio and can not be configured to output on frequencies outside of standards.

Comment: But fm radio may emit to (I know, the frequency is up to 100-120). The engineer menu show me some options like emit in 850MHz - so the device is able to work 'close'. Is it a fixed freq mode, or I cat build an app? (the phone is rooted, the app I may make, but I don't know if it is a class/interface where to start digging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this unless you have some special-purpose hardware. As someone already commented, normal Android devices don't have a radio transmitter that can be made to transmit on any frequency.

Comment: Accepted! For this purpose, I won't buy any hardware.